# javascript onclick event not bubbling up when called programmatically in internet explorer <= 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, event-bubbling

I have an anchor within an `li` element, each with their own onclick handler.

When I manually click the link, which has a # href, both onclick events are fired.  This is what I want.
When I click the link by calling `document.links[0].onclick()`, only the inner onclick event fires.

I cannot change the page itself, only the javascript to be executed.

Comment: Are you trying to fake a click event? is this for testing or as a part of your application?

Comment: @Uzi: testing.  I was having issues setting up Watin/Watir/Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just invoking the function directly - there is no event involved, thus no bubbling. You need to [trigger the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) instead.